# jQuery live() function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem with the jQuery's live() function.

I'm creating the shopping basket with PHP and make a json call to the php script to add specific item to the basket. Rather than re-binding the click to the button ( tag) I've decided to use live(), however it doesn't seem to like it.

Here's my call:

```
if ($('.add_to_basket').length > 0) {
    $('.add_to_basket').live('click', function() {
        var button = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        $.getJSON("/basket/action/add/id/" + id, function(data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                $('.basket_no_of_items').text(data.no_of_items);
                $('.basket_items_total').text(data.total);
                button.text('Remove from the basket');
            }           
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

I've checked with firebug and it seem to post the request to only /basket/action/add - without id bit.

Comment: *it doesn't seem to like it* is not a problem description. Please explain more precisely what is the expected result, the actual result and how this actual result differs than the expected result. In case you are getting an error provide the full message of this error. As this is an AJAX question providing the exact HTTP trace input/output you are seeing in FireBug might also be helpful.

Comment: What's it doing or not doing?

Comment: Did you run the code inside the `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Yes-  it's inside the $(document).ready()

Comment: Also - no warnings / no errors in the firebug - but as mentioned above - the POST seem to be sent to the incomplete url - it cuts off the id parameter.

Comment: Then there can be only one problem, the parameter `rel` is not defined on the button or its value is empty

Comment: I'm afraid it's not - here's my trigger: <a rel="27" class="button_flex add_to_basket" href="#">Add to basket!</a>

Comment: I've tried to call alert() right at the beginning of the function - but it does not pop in - this would mean that live() isn't even called - isn't that right?

Comment: Also - perhaps worth to mention - I'm using jquery-1.5.1.min - I saw one thread about 1.5.1 and live('hover') - that it didn't work correctly - perhaps it's referring to the same problem?

Comment: Another thing - could the fact that all my scripts are included in the footer affect the effectiveness of it? meaning - perhaps live() should be called before the trigger - does anyone know?

Comment: I dont understand how it can "post the request to only /basket/action/add - without id bit" and not call "the alert() right at the beginning of the function"

Comment: Guys - I must apologise to all of you - I've found the problem - because I've copied files over from the previous project - there was already script which was doing the same thing - so the function was defined twice - hence the problem. Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea of using `live()` is to register a function on the occurrence of an event (eg. click) on a set of elements whether they exist or not at the time of creation of the function.

Adding `($('.add_to_basket').length > 0)` will check whether this particular set of elements exist or not. This is counter productive as per my description above. So, either:

1. Remove `($('.add_to_basket').length > 0)` and this should work for all `.add_to_basket` elements
2. Change `$('.add_to_basket').live('click', function() {...});` to `$('.add_to_basket').click(function() {...});` and wrap it around with a `$(document).ready()` to ensure that all DOM elements have loaded when the function is registered to the click.

Hope this makes sense.

Sumit

Comment: Thanks Sumit - I've already solved the problem - please see the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "length" check, I bet it's interfering with the .live() function.

Comment: yeah, what is the length check for anyway? I saw many people using that, but am still wondering why do we need it?

Comment: I don't think it is interfering with the .live(), but it is useless  anyway

Comment: I've tried it before - but it didn't change anything - it's only checking whether the element has been found on the page.

Comment: So, why do you have it in the first place, if it didn't change anything? :)

Comment: It's not necessary 'useless' - as it prevents the chunk of script from being executed if item does not exist on the page - and prevents script from throwing any unnecessary errors by doing so.

Comment: @user This script won't throw any errors if the `.add_to_basket` element doesn't exist. Also, only attaching the event to elements that already exist kinda defeats the purpose of `.live` event handling. You can safely get rid of the `.length` check here.

Answer (score 1):

change  `$.getJSON("/basket/action/add/id/" + id, function(data) {})`
to  `$.getJSON("/basket/action/add/id/" ,{ pid : id}, function(data) {})`